# Tengo que capturar el error de logaritmo, pero su resultado es NaN

Tags: java

me sale error al ejecutar en el main el codigo, el math.log no da algun error pero una clase que maneje el error

```
   
    public class main{ 
       public static void main(String[] args) throws LogaritmoExc {
         double n1,result;
         Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.println(«Ingrese logaritmo de: «);
         n1 = sc.nextDouble();
         result= Math.log(n1);
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Las excepciones se lanzan cuando hay un problema:

```java
...
n1 = sc.nextDouble();
if (n1 <= 0 ) {
    throw new LogaritmoException("No existe el logaritmo de 0 o de números negativos");
}
result= Math.log(n1);
...
```

Tu código lanzará la excepción siempre, no hay ninguna condición para que no se lance

Comment: El error es la excepción! Lanzar una excepción es avisar de un error. Si no la capturas y la tratas termina la ejecución del código, es el comportamiento esperado

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con un try catch

```
  public class main{ 
       public static void main(String[] args) throws LogaritmoExc {
try {        

 double n1,result;
         Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.println(«Ingrese logaritmo de: «);
         n1 = sc.nextDouble();
         result= Math.log(n1);
         throw new LogaritmoExc(«Ingrese un valor >0», n1);
} catch (error){
//Capturas el error
} 
        }
```

Comment: si corre pero no me muestra el numero negativo a lo q atrapa el error, puse mi cod asi: `public class main{ 
       public static void main(String[] args) throws LogaritmoExc {
try {        

 double n1,result;
         Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.println("«Ingrese logaritmo de: «");
         n1 = sc.nextDouble();
         result= Math.log(n1);
         if(n1<0)
         throw new LogaritmoExc("Ingrese un valor >0", n1);
} catch (LogaritmoExc ex){
    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
} 
       }
  }`